# Why 'scanner is never closed ' warning doesn't disappear?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Despite writing `scanner.close()` on Line 46, why does the Warning about scanner not disappear on the Line 13?

[image: Source Code]

Comment: Post code as text, not as an image...

Comment: You have an infinite loop where you create a new scanner on every iteration. What happens in all cases where the user doesn't enter `End`? That scanner is never closed...

Comment: scanner.close() should be independent of the conditional statement and that's the reason you are getting this warning. Just try putting it at the end of your script.

Answer (score 0):

Because from compiler perspective there is no guarantee that user will type 'end' to close program. The code you wrote opens a new Scanner each loop execution. You should add `close` call outside the while loop and declare `Scanner` outside `while`, avoiding opening too many `Scanner`.